# How do you initialize a thread on the heap? (Using the "new" keyword)

Tags: c++, multithreading, oop, heap-memory

Is there a way to initialize an `std::thread`on the heap using the "new" keyword?

Comment: `new std::thread(...)`? You can put basically anything on the heap, why not `std::thread`? I'd always recommend avoiding bare `new` (`std::make_unique` is usually safer), but you do you.

Comment: Side note: doesn't the syntax `std::thread name = new std::thread(...)` create two `std::thread`s?

Comment: The same way you instantiate anything else using `new`. I'm going to regret this, but... why do yo ask ? Edit: @SuperSim135 that's supposed to be `std::thread *name = new std::thread(...);` Still curious. *why do you want to a naked pointer to own a dynamic thread object?*

Comment: That syntax would be wrong (assigning a pointer to a non-pointer). You'd want `std::thread *name = new std::thread(...);`, which definitely doesn't make two.

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm trying to manage a thread on a global scope, and when I create a thread on the stack, once I leave the member function that created the thread my program aborts. So a thread created on the heap seems to be my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use new, use `make_unique`

Something along this line:

```
#include<thread>
#include<memory>

bool fun1()
{
    return true;
}

int main() {
    auto thread1 = std::make_unique<std::thread>( fun1 );


    thread1->join();
}
```

Comment: This isn't really an answer; `new` is perfectly legal, `std::make_unique` is just a better/safer option in most cases.

Comment: @SuperSim135 auto resource management of the pointer to guarantee it's deleted

Comment: @SuperSim135: Read up on smart pointers. Raw pointers are easy to leak, smart pointers clean up on their own.

Comment: @SuperSim135 [Read this: What is RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii).

Comment: @ShadowRanger it is an answer to the main question: How do you initialise a thread on the heap ;) On the other hand, new and make_unique is extra..